# Checkout page does not work opencart 1.5.5.1

Tags: php, opencart, checkout

Suddenly my checkout page on opencart 1.5.5.1 stops working. Steps 1 to 6 do not open or respond.

The safari error console gets met the following error:
"[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"

This is the link.
http://supplementus.nl/index.php?route=checkout/checkout

The weird thing is that this happend without any change on the site.

I haven't found any answer further on the forums or internet that works for me.

Please help?

Comment: The checkout is working when I did not accept cookies. When I click on accept cookies then the checkout stops working.

Comment: fixed the problem. Probably some errors with the cookie module. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have `<script>` tag inside another `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/plain" class="cc-onconsent-analytics">
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-57249836-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script> </script>
```

Remove the inner `<script>` and `</script>` tags.

This code is near the top of the head, around line 95